# How can dos batch subscripts change a var initially defined in a calling script?

Tags: batch-file, dos

How can dos batch subscripts change a var initially defined in a calling script?   For example, this script is failing to increment the VAR variable, as expected.   This is something like a 'global variable' that I am trying to use.

one.bat

```
@echo off
ENDLOCAL
SET /A GLOBALVAR=0
cmd.exe /C two.bat
ECHO ERRORLEVEL after cmd.exe : %ERRORLEVEL%
CALL two.bat
ECHO ERRORLEVEL after CALL : %ERRORLEVEL%
ECHO GLOBALVAR=%GLOBALVAR%
pause
```

two.bat

```
@ECHO off
:: error if GLOBALVAR variable not detected
IF NOT DEFINED GLOBALVAR EXIT /B 9
SET /A GLOBALVAR=%GLOBALVAR%+1
EXIT /B 0
```

And the output:

```
ERRORLEVEL after cmd.exe : 0
ERRORLEVEL after CALL : 0
GLOBALVAR=1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: and, it's not VAR but GLOBALVAR in two.bat, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using "`cmd.exe /c two.bat`" you should use "`call two.bat`" like you are doing two lines later. This executes `two.bat` in the context of the callers environment and thus gives `two.bat` access to variable `GLOBALVAR`.

In line 3 of `two.bat`, write "`GLOBALVAR`" rather than "`VAR`". This typo (?) caused `two.bat` to exit prematurely without changing `GLOBALVAR`.

Comment: Ahh!  You are correct.  I thought 'cmd.exe /C' or 'CALL' would give me the same effect, but apparently not.